# I cant add names into list from entry

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to make quiz game in python with tk. I got stuck at adding and taking in names of the players, but when I write names into entry it prints this instead of the names: [<tkinter.Entry object .!frame.!entry>, <tkinter.Entry object .!frame.!entry2>].

```
import tkinter as tk

WIDTH = 1600
HEIGHT = 800

names = []

win = tk.Tk()
win.title('game')
win.geometry(str(WIDTH) + 'x' + str(HEIGHT))
win.attributes('-fullscreen',True)

def settings():
        
    def save():
        for widget in win.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        names.append(player1)
        names.append(player2)
        print(names)
        
    names.clear()
    
    settings = tk.Frame(win, width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT)
    settings.pack()   
    #nacitanie mien    
    name_lab = tk.Label(settings, font = ('arial', 20), text = 'Choose you names', )
    name_lab.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    
    player1 = tk.Entry(settings, font = 'arial')
    player1.grid(row = 3, column = 0)

    player1_lab = tk.Label(settings, font = 'arial', text = 'Imput  name of the player1:')
    player1_lab.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    
    player2_lab = tk.Label(settings, font = 'arial', text = 'Imput  name of the player2:')
    player2_lab.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
   
    player2 = tk.Entry(settings, font = 'arial')
    player2.grid(row = 3, column = 2)
    
    name_save = tk.Button(settings, font = 'arial', text = 'Save', command = save)
    name_save.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
    
settings()

win.mainloop()
```

I also tried using function get(), but that doesnt work either, it just gives me empty quotation marks instead of the names.

```
import tkinter as tk

WIDTH = 1600
HEIGHT = 800

names = []

win = tk.Tk()
win.title('game')
win.geometry(str(WIDTH) + 'x' + str(HEIGHT))
win.attributes('-fullscreen',True)

def settings():
        
    def save():
        for widget in win.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        names.append(player1n)
        names.append(player2n)
        print(names)
        
    names.clear()
    
    settings = tk.Frame(win, width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT)
    settings.pack()   
    #nacitanie mien    
    name_lab = tk.Label(settings, font = ('arial', 20), text = 'Choose you names', )
    name_lab.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    
    player1 = tk.Entry(settings, font = 'arial')
    player1.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
    player1n = player1.get

    player1_lab = tk.Label(settings, font = 'arial', text = 'Imput  
    name of the player1:')
    player1_lab.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    
    player2_lab = tk.Label(settings, font = 'arial', text = 'Imput  
    name of the player2:')
    player2_lab.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
   
    player2 = tk.Entry(settings, font = 'arial')
    player2.grid(row = 3, column = 2)
    player2n = player2.get
    
    name_save = tk.Button(settings, font = 'arial', text = 'Save', 
    command = save)
    name_save.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
    
settings()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you make the texts English, please?

Comment: I hope its better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare two `StringVar` to hold the contents of the inputs to the `Entry`'s.

```
import tkinter as tk

WIDTH = 1600
HEIGHT = 800

names = []

win = tk.Tk()
win.title('game')
win.geometry(str(WIDTH) + 'x' + str(HEIGHT))
win.attributes('-fullscreen',True)

def nastavenia():
        
    def save():
        for widget in win.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        
        # Append the inputs to the list.
        names.append(var.get())
        names.append(var2.get())
       
        

    # Deleted names.clear()
 
    var = tk.StringVar() # String variable no. 1
    var2=tk.StringVar() # String variable no. 2
    
    nastavenia = tk.Frame(win, width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT)
    nastavenia.pack()   
    #nacitanie mien    
    name_lab = tk.Label(nastavenia, font = ('arial', 20), text = 'Zvol si typ hry', )
    name_lab.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    
    sin = tk.Entry(nastavenia, font = 'arial', textvariable=var)
    sin.grid(row = 3, column = 0)

    sin_lab = tk.Label(nastavenia, font = 'arial', text = 'Zadaj meno 1. hraca')
    sin_lab.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    
    mut_lab = tk.Label(nastavenia, font = 'arial', text = 'Zadaj meno 2. hraca')
    mut_lab.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
   
    mut = tk.Entry(nastavenia, font = 'arial', textvariable=var2)
    mut.grid(row = 3, column = 2)
    
    name_save = tk.Button(nastavenia, font = 'arial', text = 'Save', command = save)
    name_save.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
    
   

nastavenia()

win.mainloop()
```

Now the `names` gets filled with your input.

Edit: You had already had a variable named `names`.